# How to set TTL on outgoing packets in perl?

Tags: perl, ip, ttl

How do I set the `Time-To-Live` socket option in perl?

What are the parameters to `setsockopt()`, or is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

The following works for me, on Linux:

IPv4

```
use Socket;
...
socket (SOCKET, ...) or die "Can't create socket: $!";
my $ip = getprotobyname ('ip'); # just in case it ever changes ;-)
my $opname = IP_TTL;
my $opval = int $ttl; # if $ttl is a string, convert to int
setsockopt (SOCKET, $ip, $opname, $opval) or warn "setsockopt failed: $!";
```

IPv6

```
use Socket("SOCK_STREAM", "IPV6_UNICAST_HOPS");
...
my $ipv6 = getprotobyname('ipv6');
my $opname = IPV6_UNICAST_HOPS; 
my $opval = int $ttl;
setsockopt (SOCKET,$ipv6,$opname,$opval) or warn "setsockopt failed: $!";
```